# Unable to read JSON in PHP on FTP

Tags: php, jquery, json, ftp, highcharts

I have an FTP setup on zymic.com. I have a jsonfile names testJson.json and a php file named index.php (obviously the default). I have some temperature data in the testJson.json file coming from a sensor. I want to display that onto the website (index.php) using highcharts. I have both testJson.json and index.php file on the same directory.
Although I believe that I am doing right but I am not getting the results. Below is my code of index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript"      src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
   $.getJSON('testJson.json', function(data) {
      // Create temperature chart
      $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
         rangeSelector : {
    selected : 1
     },
         title : {
    text : 'Temperature graph in °C'
     }, 
     series : [{
    name : 'Temperature',
    data : data,
    tooltip: {
       valueDecimals: 2
    }
     }]
      });
   });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="Highstock-1.3.2/js/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="Highstock-1.3.2/js/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 500px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is your $.getJSON actually even opening the file ?

Comment: I think the answer is below, but in the future try using something like FireFox to check for javascript errors.  Just hit Ctrl+shift+j to pull up the error console.  It probably would have told you there was something wrong with the .highcharts call.

Comment: Show your JSON example, please. Code looks properly.

Comment: [
[1371824100000, 22.30],
[1371825000000, 23.20],
[1371825900000, 22.50],
[1371826800000, 22.90],
[1371827700000, 23.00],
[1371828600000, 23.90],
[1371829500000, 24.00],
[1371830400000, 23.00],
[1371831300000, 23.40],
[1371832200000, 22.97],
[1371833100000, 22.27],
]

Here is my testJson.json file

Please note that when I use the following json the code works fine
{"name":"John"}
but both jsons are valid as I have verified both of them on http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/. But here in the code the second one works only.

Comment: Your json looks like proerly, so maybe json is not loaded? (cross-domain problem ?)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to put your script after you load the hightstock.js and exporting.js

Comment: It didn't worked. May be there is some other method to read json ??